# I need to create a public app for shopify in php

Tags: php, shopify

Here I am new for shopify and I would like to create a simple app that i can install on my multiple stores but before that i want to understand how to authenticate app

I downloaded the code from here https://github.com/phpish/shopify_app-skeleton 
and added that code in my www/shopify_app

I created the app here you can see what i added in text box not sure if correct info added or not https://snag.gy/lnASuB.jpg
**My shop : https://softodev.myshopify.com**
where i would like to install that app

As per guide point no 4 https://snag.gy/4hbcmK.jpg

I just hit the http://localhost/shopify_app/install.php?shop=softodev.myshopify.com
and got the error  https://snag.gy/HrcgYV.jpg  not sure if I am missing something please suggest so that i can install the app to check how it work

Conf file : https://snag.gy/RfFyzT.jpg

https://snag.gy/5suj3B.jpg

Comment: You are stopping at `shopify\is_valid_request($_GET, SHOPIFY_APP_SHARED_SECRET) or die('Invalid Request! Request or redirect did not come from Shopify');` Please recheck your `app secret`....  and also check your `is_valid_request` function in `shopify.php`

Comment: Yes I know it stopping me here but why ? 
 I will check but have you checked if backend alll setting seems  ok like callback url and redirection url 
I have a bit doubt on my redirection url

Comment: Please keep both same `callback url` and `redirect url` , then try again. In your case `redirect url` should also be `http://localhost/shopify_app/oauth.php`

Comment: see the function 

https://snag.gy/OjspZE.jpg 

In param I am getting this Array
(
    [hmac] => d4403dfcdb54fc1e7b799a265feea6aa78777150d6fe39ce79aeb1424b7f1479
    [shop] => softodev.myshopify.com
    [timestamp] => 1487676503
)

Comment: Here is I made edits https://snag.gy/aoq1rY.jpg

Comment: Now it should work just fine... If not please use a live server

Comment: Have you checked the snag.gy/aoq1rY.jpg it looking for 

$signature = $query_params['signature']; see https://snag.gy/fK9H2U.jpg 

IN my params I dont have signature what is that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136240/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-chauhan).

Comment: @Chauhan, Did you get solution of this, i am also implementing it. can you please help me.